# Passwordless ssh tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, password, ssh-tunneling

I have my local machine (a mac), and I want to access server B (linux). Server B needs to be accessed through server A (linux). I have set up a tunnel by modifying the .ssh/config file in my local machine as follows:

```
Host serverB
 HostName serverB.com
 User Ant
 ProxyCommand ssh -q -Y serverA.com -W %h:%p
```

This used to work correctly[0]. Next, I set up passwordless login from local to serverA and from serverA to serverB using ssh keys. This means that I can do

```
> ssh Ant@serverA.com
(serverA)> ssh Ant@serverB.com
(serverB)>
```

and everything works properly. Now what I want is to be able to connect to server B without passwords; but if I do

```
> ssh Ant@severB.com
```

I am asked the passwords to severA and B to keep going. This is the output of `ssh -v Ant@serverB`:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/Ant/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/Ant/.ssh/config line 16: Applying options for serverB
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -q -Y serverA.com -W serverB.com:22
debug1: identity file /Users/Ant/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Ant/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Ant/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Ant/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Ant/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Ant/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Ant/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/Ant/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 501
Ant@serverA.com's password:
```

I can see that it is *trying* to use the key login but something is going wrong. Let me also add that my RSA key is saved into a non-standard location, so I added this to my .ssh/config file:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_serverA
```

Any thoughts?

[0]: For some reason this does not work anymore, as the username is wrong. It prompts me for my password at local_username@serverA.com rather than Ant@serverA.com

Comment: IIRC, you need to setup passwordless login for both serverA and serverB on the local machine to be able to tunnel to serverB through serverA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `User` option in a `Host` section is only applied for connections matching that host, and not necessarily for any commands started for proxying, etc., for which ssh config settings will be independently applied.

So either the `ProxyCommand` should explicitly have `Ant@serverA`, or there should be another `Host` block that `serverA` matches, setting `User Ant` for it.

Answer (score 0):

This solution was proposed by the author of the question:

> I found a solution. The problem was that, for some reason, ssh tried
> to access serverA using local_username rather than Ant (the username
> on serverA and serverB). To solve the issue I modified the config
> tunnel command by explicitly adding my username:
>
> ```
> Host serverB
>  HostName serverB.com
>  User Ant
>  ProxyCommand ssh -q -Y Ant@serverA.com -W %h:%p
> ```
>
> This fixed the issue and now passwordless login works with serverB
> too! :-)